# Printing on next line every time char is reached

Tags: java, arrays

In my code I first add two string arrays to a String arrayList. In my toString() method I want to print the arrayList so that every time char ',' is reached, we print the next array, on the next line (in a row). but with this code I get a row of the first array and a column of the second. what am I doing wrong here?

[image: click here for output]

**Code :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class PrintList {
    static String[] data = {"cat","dog"," ","hen",","};
    static String[] data2 = {"ttt","yyy","ggg","ddd", ","};
    static ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dataRecord();
        System.out.print(listToString(list));
    }

    public static void dataRecord () {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(data2));

    }
    public static String listToString (List <?> list) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           result += "      " + list.get(i);
           if (result.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
              result = result + System.lineSeparator();
           }
        }
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Comment: as a side note, don't concatenate strings inside a loop, using a StringBuilder would be more memory friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's some strange code there but I assume it's a learning excercise so it's fine I guess. Your problem is that once your result string contains a comma you add the line separator each time you add a new element.

Example: assume your list contains `"a", "b", ",", "c", "d"`.

Now you iterate and add the elements to a string which then looks like this:

- you add `"a"`, the string looks like `"a"`
- you add `"b"`, the string looks like `"a      b"`
- you add `","`, the string looks like `"a      b      ,"`, now for the first time your string contains a comma so you add the line separator and thus the string looks like `"a      b      ,\n"`
- you add `"c"`, the string looks like `"a      b      ,\n      c"`. Because there's still a comma in your string another line separtor is added and the string is `"a      b      ,\n      c\n"`.
- you add `"d"`, the string looks like `"a      b      ,\n      c\n      d"`. Because there's still a comma in your string another line separtor is added and the string is `"a      b      ,\n      c\n      d\n"`.

To fix that you have several possibilities:

- check whether the element you just added is a comma or contains one. If so add the line separator (and maybe don't add the element)
- add the elements without any check and replace the commas at the end (after your loop), e.g. via `result = result.replace(",", ",\n");`

Comment: thanks for the answer! what would be a "less strange" code since it is a learning exercise. thanks

Comment: @hozan well, for one adding commas to a list, then concatenating it all into a string and afterwards replacing the commas with something else isn't exactly the sort of code you'd use in production :) Additionally instead of keeping a static list you'd probably create one inside `dataRecord()` (that name's not very descriptive btw) and return it from that method. Thats just two things and there are more but touching them all would be way out of scope for SO and normally you'll get those as you gain experience.

Answer (score 2):

Just change this if:

```
if (result.indexOf(',') >= 0)
```

for this one:

```
if (list.get(i).indexOf(',') >= 0)
```

the problem is that you are always looking in the result variable. When the first ',' appears the result will always contains the ','.